# how to work with a network socket (if correct term) in general and in Chrome

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-console

I have encountered something new in Chrome which I've not seen before and am unfamiliar with.  It appears to be some type of persistent socket (best term I know of).

Up to now I've been familiar with each AJAX call being the way to contact a server, each with a request/response if the connection is successful.  And each one would show in the `Name` column in the console.  Plus, I could "`Replay XHR`" as an option.  And the tabs Headers/Preview/Response/Timing were helpful.  However this appears to be grouped and the data I see in the chat window I can't find in any of the JSON objects on the list.  What is the correct name for this, and is there any way to see the individual headers/response from each call?

This is a screenshot:

[image: Chrome console screenshot]

Comment: This is called Web Sockets.  They aren't multiple requests.

Comment: But all back-and-forth communication with the server via that socket will be in the Frames tab, correct?

Comment: That is correct.